# Href link color in table

Tags: php, html, css

I have an html table with a href link in a cell and I dont know how can I set this href link color. Background color (red) works okay but the simple "color: green" no.

```
else if($row['OK']=='OK') // if the word is OK
            echo "<td style='background-color: red;'><div id='bot'><a href='nyugtaz.php?callsign=".$row['callsign']."'>$nyugtaze</a></div></td>";

The code is what I tried:

else if($row['OK']=='OK') // if the word is OK
            echo "<td style='background-color: red; color: green'><div id='bot'><a href='nyugtaz.php?callsign=".$row['callsign']."'>$nyugtaze</a></div></td>";
```

Comment: please write the code you tried and did not work

Comment: edit the question instead of writing in the comment please

Comment: The color of the ancestor element likely does not get inherited by your link, resp. the color for that might be specifically overwritten. Instead of creating inline styles, you should be doing this by only adding a class to the td element, and then handle the rest via your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid adding inline styles.

Your document will be simpler to read and maintain with an external stylesheet.

Conditionally add a class to the table cell, then leverage that class in your stylesheet.

```
} elseif ($row['OK'] == 'OK') {
    echo "<td class='okCell'><div id='bot'><a href='nyugtaz.php?callsign=".$row['callsign']."'>{$nyugtaze}</a></div></td>";
```

CSS:

```
.okCell {
    background-color: red;
}
.okCell a {   # handle all of the linked/visited/etc variations if you wish
    color: green;
}
```

I am sure I could advise a cleaner way to code this up, but you haven't offered much context.

P.s. I hope that `id='bot'` is unique to the page.

Answer (score -1):

Try following CSS will help you.

```css
#bot a:link, #bot a:visited{
 
 color:black;
}
#bot a:hover{
 color:green;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td style='background-color: red;'><div id='bot'><a href='nyugtaz.php?callsign=".$row['callsign']."'>test</a></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It changes all of the links not only the "OK" words. I want to change only the OK words color and background color.

Comment: in that case you can use #bot check updated snippet